# Fair algorithm to distribute work to nodes without being unfair to producers

Tags: algorithm, queue, distributed, distributed-computing

I got the following problem and I m looking for some ideas.

I got N producers of work and M consumers. N producers produce work and put it to Q messages queues, which are monitored by consumers.

so we have

```
N    ->         -> M       In this example N producers put work in a round robin 
N    ->    Q    -> M       fashion to Q queues which are monitored for new work
N    ->         -> M       in a round robin fashion from M consumers
N    ->    Q    -> M
N    ->         -> M
N    ->    Q    -> M
N    ->         -> M
                -> M
                -> M
```

Assume the following example:

N1 has 100 work items to produce
N2 has 1 work items to produce
N3 has 1 work item to produce

Assume there is Q1 and Q2

N1 pushes 100 work items to Q1
N2 pushes 1 work items to Q2
N3 pushes 1 work item to Q1 (cause its round robin)

N3 will wait till all of N1s work has completed.

I am looking for a way to distribute work between N and M in a more even and fair way.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I am not too fussed about consumer starving as this never happens (cause there is enough work for everyone).

Comment: If a single producer queues items 1, 2, and 3, do you expect them to be processed in that order? Or can they be processed in the order 3, 2, 1?

Comment: They can be processed in any order. I dont care if its 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an algorithm like below would be helpful for you, it makes the tiniest change possible in you RR algorithm so you dont need to change a lot:

```
work(Product product) {
    if (product is small)
        put in queue
    else {
        split product into independent parts
        fork new subtasks to solve each part
        join all subtasks
        compose result from subresults
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly it is part of workstealing algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to change your queues so that they aren't queues of items, but queues of producer records, each of which contains a queue of items. So if you have N producers, each queue will have at most N entries. Each entry contains a list (queue) of jobs from that producer.

A consumer then dequeues a producer record from the queue, removes the next job for that producer from the producer record, and then adds the producer back to the queue. The consumer then goes on to process that job. If the consumer removes the last job from the producer record, don't add the producer back to the queue. It will be re-created the next time that producer enqueues a job.

I did something very similar to that with a Web crawler project a while back. It worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you described is how you interpreted RR for your problem, I’d interpret it differently:

every producer will fill up one queue after another. Here is still a small problem, since for your example Q1 would contain 52 tasks (half from N1 plus N2+N3) and Q2 would contain only 50 tasks, but this difference might be considered rather negligible.

However if all producers would produce at exactly the same rate, they would bombard always the same qeueu with messages which is also not good so let’s combine your and mine solution, by changing the qeueu where the initial task is sent to:

> N1 starts with Q1, N2 starts with Q2 and N3 again with Q1

this way we’d end up with 51:51 split

---

if you don’t care about the order in which the qeueus will be filled up, you can also simply choose by random. This is a surprisingly efficient and equally distributed solution which doesn’t require virtually any algorithm. However equal distribution only applies if your number of tasks which are distributed is any large. Also all tasks should be roughly the same size, as only the number of tasks is equally distributed and not the amount of work - but this also applies for the previously mentione RR adaptations.